Is my 240v outlet wiring adequate for a welder?
My garage has a 240v outlet and when I tried to switch the breaker on it tripped the main.  The garage has a breaker box that is wired into the main house box. The main box (200 amp service) has two 20amp breakers wired to the garage box and the 240 in the garage is a double pole 60 amp breaker.  Why would this trip my main and how can I fix this? I would like to be able to run a wire welder on this 240.

Was something plugged in to the receptacle when the breaker tripped? You write as if the breaker tripped without anything plugged in or turned on (at least you fail to mention anything being plugged in or turned on.) That would be a pretty clear sign of a major wiring error. If you had sometjing plugged in and turned on, [edit] the question to clarify that point. Might as well include some pictures of the main and sub-panels as well.

Nothing plugged in. All I did was flip on the 60amp breaker and the main breaker to the house tripped. This breaker in my garage has never been on.  I just noticed it was ran to a 220 outlet and was hoping it was hooked up so I could run my welder. The main has 2 30amp breakers supplying power to the garage box via 4 12-2 wires ( 2 from each breaker).

Then you have a code violation (as already mentioned in another comment) and a major wiring error (not that surprising when you have code violations in the wiring.)

Nominal voltages in North America are 120/240 since the 1950s. Are you somewhere else? Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour].

The wires are two #12 cables. Romex perhaps? Not good outdoors.  Are they in conduit? How hard would they be to swap for 6-6-6-6 aluminum or 2-2-2-4 aluminum?

So you are trying to pull 60 amps (or more than 20) from 20 amp breakers?
And are wondering why a breaker tripped?
Amps pulled must be less than the breaker size (amps).
To fix, do a load calculation, then if enough, change the wires to 60 amp size, then you can change the the breaker in main panel to 60 amps.
Or change the welder to an inverter type that only uses 20 amps at 240v.

So your saying I need to take the 60 amp breaker out. Then I need to change my main breakers from 20amp to something larger then get the same for the garage box.

@James   And the wires.  The breaker protects the wires from burning up inside of your walls.  An inverter welder will work well at 20 amps and relatively cheap.  The breaker in the main panel protects the wires to the garage.  So the wires might be only 12 gauge(for 20 amp breaker).  The wire gauge and the breaker in the main panel allows what power/amps you can have/use in the garage.  Get larger gauge wires for 60 amps or reduce the amount of amps you need for welding.

I really appreciate your time.   After looking my box over a little closer I  seem to have 30amp breakers not 20.  And the wiring that goes out to the garage box is 12-2 but I have 2 wires coming from each of those breakers to the garage. 4 total hot. Does this sound right? Could I put a 30amp breaker in my garage and be ok?

@James  That sounds illeagal and dangerous.  12/2 is only good for 20 amps at 120 volts.  For a 240v circuit you need 12/3 or larger.  Right now you should turn off those breakers and keep them off till that circuit is done right.  If the house burns down, your insurance will laugh in your face if you start a claim.

I will do that. I guess that could be why the breaker has been off since I purchased the house. Thanks.
